# C# : Get node name onClick in TreeView for a file manager

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have to create a file manager from scratch and im stuck in the begining.

It must show all drives name letter first.
Then onclick shows folders an files in childnode and ... .

Here is my **question**:

1. How can i get node name (as a string) which is clicked ?
2. Is it the right way to doing this?

---

Here i first get drives name letter:

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        for (var i = 0; i < drives.Count(); i++)
        {
            var drivesletter = drives[i].Name;
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(drivesletter);
        }
```

Here i created a method, when you click on each node, **node name should be saved in a Variable**, then it will get list of all files and folders in it and add them to the node that we clicked on it:

```
private void treeView1_Click(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        var nodename = treeView1.Nodes.Find("*", true); //this line suppose to get clicked node name
        var getdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(nodename); //error: It says nodename isnt string type
        foreach (var getdir in getdirs)
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(getdir);
        }
    }
```

If you have any source, example or something simple like what im going to make, its a big help.

Comment: try e.Node, thats the node you clicked

Comment: tryed in Directory.GetDirectories(e.Node) it says itsnot string type

Comment: What about `e.Node.ToString()` or `nodename.ToString()`?

Comment: @DewinaAgain Yes because a node is not a string, as waka said use `.ToString()`

Comment: tryed it too: `var tns = e.Node.ToString();` then `Directory.GetDirectories(tns);` it says this path is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to return `Node` Name:

```
protected void treeView1_AfterSelect (object sender,   
System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs e)  
{  
   // Determine by checking the Text property.  
   MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);  
}
```

Comment: used this `Directory.GetDirectories(e.Node.Text);` and Worked perfect.